# How to update data in Mysql table from Pyspark

Tags: mysql, pyspark

I am able to read data from mysql table in pyspark via

```
hiveContext.read.format('jdbc').options(url=jdbc_url, dbtable=mysql_query,driver='com.mysql.jdbc.Driver').load()
```

but I am not able to find a way to update records in mysql. has anyone ever performed an update from pyspark.

Answer (score 1):

No updates are allowed. You can only:

- `append`.
- `overwrite`

For updates or other fine grained modifications use standard database client directly.